# What is the exact keyword to retrieve pharmacy information in Google API's

Tags: javascript, php, ios, google-maps

I use the "Hospitals" keyword to retrieve the information from Google Maps using the Places API.

Here is an example query:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=51.498828,-0.117844&radius=500&types=hospital&key=xxxxxx

This returns me these results:

```
{
   "html_attributions" : [],
   "results" : [
      {
         "geometry" : {
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 51.498828,
               "lng" : -0.117844
            }
         },
         "icon" : "http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/generic_business-71.png",
         "id" : "79280ece6eb23e52ddd9e1468c2e57d672027780",
         "name" : "St Thomas' Hospital (Guy's and St Thomas' NHS Foundation Trust)",
         "photos" : [
            {
               "height" : 1246,
               "html_attributions" : [],
               "photo_reference" : "CnRnAAAAUi1zZSI4YbJrRD7qjspX3WeE-9jzkRa1_hDx-e4G10sXMifYDDUAgnRurzVGgEeMBnAt8jyJM9UvhaLSC_D-nAaLMpmXBsRoOtn7AqCS3m-OmanGhQ33vXeO6bdkVa1QdfeOE6-k2rBD1mh4r3492BIQQsExmHt96RXeCw0O4egAZRoUxrBwO5jGahBsF9kZFfljM4sBB-k",
               "width" : 2048
            }
         ],
         "place_id" : "ChIJe4cW3cAEdkgR0RK8zGZJPAQ",
         "rating" : 4.6,
         "reference" : "CqQBkwAAAMb8B3yhxUtOzcN0KYoBSe6OSne_bfCwM3eIvaZ7knxavIW5bwKCRvv0jhieHjTY7Yk54oTWEt8La2-MsD8rVZyw8bUpD40cF-DpliRiXTCqmx56Xsb_-cWzqiQfDalKWCRHuDu12gOTa_wGP8g2zs-bXvTbb0jQWHuMT3iwB2qfvFk4JTMdSc3MApQ-HvlajoLt1jM1eIPbi4T49IsTyt0SEFdLVGn2Mt7nUn-EWjKS3ZgaFE_6ix8HgRpTxZbZ_846vFHJ6GGE",
         "scope" : "GOOGLE",
         "types" : [ "hospital", "establishment" ],
         "vicinity" : "Westminster Bridge Road, London"
      },
      {
         "geometry" : {
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 51.49789,
               "lng" : -0.119007
            }
         },
         "icon" : "http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/generic_business-71.png",
         "id" : "af49dc43752dfa4474372dd2d104326391f5c922",
         "name" : "Evelina London Children's Hospital",
         "place_id" : "ChIJe4cW3cAEdkgRaAH_sCAYGFY",
         "reference" : "CoQBdQAAABmGD2avavpdHE_lPKkd0NgzCKlE2HB7K1FLWprc-5HnK8tjLV_ANiqH64zDXDu5X1dm4kP_f2IMnCvH3rqldVum-yFSAy797yJ7ziRfzIs-bEVONQmHywsELF7jYQidhBjvNcVVtSZIqKt9bGaisHBlAgSfVZLvBLILp0Pus6aFEhCWiXL0_41bKrAi-65YFYwVGhRi8VtKquPi28zVbvwM0SiOqXWRSA",
         "scope" : "GOOGLE",
         "types" : [ "hospital", "establishment" ],
         "vicinity" : "St Thomas's Hospital, Westminster Bridge Road, London"
      },
      {
         "geometry" : {
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 51.495612,
               "lng" : -0.112609
            }
         },
         "icon" : "http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/generic_business-71.png",
         "id" : "bfdfecb4b4b83a281688f9e7398edfc432f775e2",
         "name" : "Lambeth Walk Group Practice",
         "opening_hours" : {
            "open_now" : true,
            "weekday_text" : []
         },
         "photos" : [
            {
               "height" : 665,
               "html_attributions" : [],
               "photo_reference" : "CnRnAAAA7rE8nuB2f-jXftJKOq_7IfglbR9110aU9fanDkZeexE-Y9yCBun379AqA1xXiAy5MTqYsHX2UzlguZKPx6UvVu5KSUyA_nVGdFlPZNVabE4VNtUieqe3-2SHPpAkDNIIsNq7jJQSOMOrWDxt1gpQfxIQsHSIe-D-KyUncQIO_0_btxoUf_Lo1tYTA_RH2-ZWKOurjlvgyPo",
               "width" : 665
            }
         ],
         "place_id" : "ChIJTQVSab4EdkgRdgo-A3rEf-Q",
         "reference" : "CnRvAAAAR8eruaYIGRQASbKV48w-LzXBZ-LpbFk4T34zgWx-SSEtRNLHcFIASxWLQf0-0JGLPYM1SW9uUKaEAD3pmPp7qAQ8yyAYe3tGT0HXZLgstkyN8FHmN8ZH9bBWCj530Jc0tB_ydLvdIh1aFlaNJWRFNBIQ5fiFENmSPTgfmMsJQqY1xxoULNazmJ-oF_jLMk5MjI1ecgYD9zk",
         "scope" : "GOOGLE",
         "types" : [ "hospital", "health", "establishment" ],
         "vicinity" : "5 Lambeth Walk, London"
      },
      {
         "geometry" : {
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 51.498781,
               "lng" : -0.11793
            }
         },
         "icon" : "http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/generic_business-71.png",
         "id" : "f8c058454bda8ff51e9fd9d44667f5838ee634b5",
         "name" : "Accident and Emergency",
         "place_id" : "ChIJjzFgrsAEdkgRXfGJmOI62HI",
         "reference" : "CnRpAAAAIDUUb8IehVUWIBEZ9Othy9iBd0Lhgwq4dbH1uyOXBvfuFWsYz5qTuOa64TWtYJLj5CYx5HrJyjL43ZP_M0L_3IarIWM0IA5BnCbwNv4-l99f82bbvm-K-A9A_FY3h8sjj02eP4_iFrktjtVrVcrlWBIQgnOimXlTjJkd1d2SEax7axoU5op9TWQrJ5UA_E0aF2UywwVAjqQ",
         "scope" : "GOOGLE",
         "types" : [ "hospital", "establishment" ],
         "vicinity" : "London"
      },
      {
         "geometry" : {
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 51.497986,
               "lng" : -0.118939
            }
         },
         "icon" : "http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/generic_business-71.png",
         "id" : "c57b042eeb2251d822fb619ecfa3b0d8b575616c",
         "name" : "Saint Thomas' House",
         "place_id" : "ChIJ4TJdwMAEdkgRJ-iwlvvPUAI",
         "reference" : "CnRmAAAAAHidGvC0I6TV4t2e-Og9QpTXng8omvf44J4g1UmimUhSusgaFB6OFxqyvY13jnwFZYmBVglVO__Vlk8LW4VvMdMe4_3sTaS_Ade9zBDWUH8CAe-U-tNzrjGbHFDXa9RvcuGyZNZ52BOOXJTJFKpwvhIQVpgc-heoE5DP2MrOjcSriBoU9PlB2Z0QEMGc2NcK7Kkd4qoj6o8",
         "scope" : "GOOGLE",
         "types" : [ "hospital", "establishment" ],
         "vicinity" : "London"
      },
      {
         "geometry" : {
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 51.499519,
               "lng" : -0.119414
            }
         },
         "icon" : "http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/generic_business-71.png",
         "id" : "e8b157bae5f7adb90a689fdd1009f23bcfeef0a5",
         "name" : "North Wing",
         "place_id" : "ChIJbR-BMccEdkgR7NBZSUVrYrk",
         "reference" : "CmReAAAAvq1S00xVA7GSi1x1vDoR1U-RtrH5XNsYaKYq6faSUGlcTThqyLANN5oy3JHoqKbACia10qQt031yYLL5g8B46StfGNQSo63Bi_bDx1Ey3tnbSKqtnlO80ssXRnixNIfvEhAqwJ0WHDl1CWXyrfAT1J9NGhTmWccD7Zn11VfuqmAQXvvu2XKv2w",
         "scope" : "GOOGLE",
         "types" : [ "hospital", "establishment" ],
         "vicinity" : "London"
      },
      {
         "geometry" : {
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 51.503286,
               "lng" : -0.115213
            }
         },
         "icon" : "http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/generic_business-71.png",
         "id" : "1d95ea8f73473e877cc7ab820da027e7d169ca3d",
         "name" : "Waterloo Health Clinic",
         "opening_hours" : {
            "open_now" : true,
            "weekday_text" : []
         },
         "photos" : [
            {
               "height" : 688,
               "html_attributions" : [],
               "photo_reference" : "CoQBcQAAAAsL6v5tOKqkWS-LkixmL1cUWZj3mTsPdRXyzcW67f2zAFC9eg3KdK2DXd5cMOwdi4tNibVMth2HcfgInD-_mOVi0dhkQh8wI7nnntHVJYX0aJkCwO39Tqw5U5P242so_E--9WY7jmEvabDf4--0aYs3aJldbATSTeA17LTNzZk5EhB-NXyk7NBGq8ZRhca5tn9yGhSLYpoxBN0cmds9i-Sl5CDYXcNrIw",
               "width" : 688
            }
         ],
         "place_id" : "ChIJz1grOLgEdkgRXM49MDBv8BU",
         "reference" : "CnRpAAAA-EPvN9hbJETcl4GVKgHd_j81GyjumbOe7vbC2auhtSIufxdSaQZi2pknJSym8-fC14GaF4JYHkwcIMHDwBveBFbtEVLmSHAdvf6brjf4eBrOJpcsfCigsg9z27mT0tpYzAvYzUAOz1RkrKT94kBS8BIQK0AEyeJxRcjk_doBY8LdyxoUvyO8Jlq598ZnW4q3txBCZg6s8Dg",
         "scope" : "GOOGLE",
         "types" : [ "hospital", "establishment" ],
         "vicinity" : "41 York Road, London"
      },
      {
         "geometry" : {
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 51.500268,
               "lng" : -0.118097
            }
         },
         "icon" : "http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/generic_business-71.png",
         "id" : "beb3c35b7d81705a922c2f419c4eed1abe523900",
         "name" : "Gasiot House",
         "place_id" : "ChIJ073IXMcEdkgRa7j7geKVnbA",
         "reference" : "CmRgAAAAAt6linpkPCZDm4Q5Eg9osTiVPJQnd4dfzCaF4ZjcoIY9HRuth-rRv3fpY2E1Cq4AMGKrSMItxl17GuWSg5wggIt0Ytc50x615eHBvHAfj4kERmQWKL-t_tm4TPvPk1PiEhBoC7XtxmIGUK3Vkroa0gh9GhT4cPKGlDMSRA543N3QzcdK8YjeMQ",
         "scope" : "GOOGLE",
         "types" : [ "hospital", "establishment" ],
         "vicinity" : "London"
      },
      {
         "geometry" : {
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 51.498809,
               "lng" : -0.118526
            }
         },
         "icon" : "http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/generic_business-71.png",
         "id" : "7924c44aae4dcdb301bb57a9146b941c2fc7a79c",
         "name" : "East Wing",
         "place_id" : "ChIJ75mktsAEdkgREbIQj3jlGH4",
         "reference" : "CmRcAAAASJbVDvFHE0ZZk3SbwCWc4ZxwoaVImMLCGiVD3MNmddnLOhev_t15B9eXex6r18RAzkuTwN6hjL4UEL1bfnjxb0EaiOd71djuqLPJqMPb31vlb4OK37FW9GP_IW5_q6hAEhAnPz6N24h8v8sHdwoN66uhGhRBgHnPasMywKURsf5lC5_rUSvQnA",
         "scope" : "GOOGLE",
         "types" : [ "hospital", "establishment" ],
         "vicinity" : "London"
      },
      {
         "geometry" : {
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 51.499425,
               "lng" : -0.11817
            }
         },
         "icon" : "http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/generic_business-71.png",
         "id" : "269d595296b45bcdc74b797f3088a665e59ef9f4",
         "name" : "Lambeth Wing",
         "place_id" : "ChIJzy-TTccEdkgRlp7ySpkaHHQ",
         "reference" : "CmRfAAAAH7uuDse-FBKUo77H1BLPa4Kn2k3O9CajB27V4fyGKA1UziQNCjE7Kwc8Qb6WteWXqfhwVo_DLXxigUnbP0r48b2lcfYmUUibgAyZjgQq965uMLuAdKaJAj8s0M5Q_GM4EhDvgeELCA1z_ZOZvp4IyeX6GhTQHdk-NY3ozCtaRWuHUn8Jr0fzKw",
         "scope" : "GOOGLE",
         "types" : [ "hospital", "establishment" ],
         "vicinity" : "London"
      },
      {
         "geometry" : {
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 51.498445,
               "lng" : -0.119751
            }
         },
         "icon" : "http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/generic_business-71.png",
         "id" : "611b92c085c3f2f64caee6261e6aa64618459757",
         "name" : "South Wing",
         "place_id" : "ChIJ117v2sAEdkgRjZ2RdXiuA2c",
         "reference" : "CmRdAAAAAtr7Q3C7tHDh7l_GiQ7TqUE6CYqIjhuU3uSglZ_-Ds9QfUf6RK_t06DhkI065vYJqhj7CizQBeNVLxkmXHJ_bxcIi5zm7xPexArIQc_p2jvAICG9-eXirnnd6UICVx35EhD-qzIZswyHvdGScNkX0LnZGhQp2sPbdxqI3S8eS9uYrKizCvzgqQ",
         "scope" : "GOOGLE",
         "types" : [ "hospital", "establishment" ],
         "vicinity" : "London"
      },
      {
         "geometry" : {
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 51.497504,
               "lng" : -0.120109
            }
         },
         "icon" : "http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/generic_business-71.png",
         "id" : "3bc8f1f1e45463e3e8bd613691b435d3218519ec",
         "name" : "Prideaux Building (King's College London, St Thomas' Campus)",
         "place_id" : "ChIJBaHT48AEdkgRG1rS1R-3Ivs",
         "reference" : "CqQBkQAAAESNeX_zc9eWdJC_XFSLaL2p66yDDYFCqDpXTXiBBnYwFatOXkwfyt-hlePQUuaWGVnQOppfpHogUjxjw6aJ7Fa9EHoU6uapeoXfDe0-4yttMwRXZ7YnBWaAtMXgNNR4GDeKkbYZ_9FYsHEm_3kMDKDXyGL54Xw-ehw_AGOy0hnCUeMYmTAxp-A9sbIjupjAEWC7festt9sIXHMhcuiXpEASEFaCxhmSelqO7IPkfNPOiboaFCNB5p-2iTMzRcz5XVTYYcC5Rgt3",
         "scope" : "GOOGLE",
         "types" : [ "hospital", "establishment" ],
         "vicinity" : "London"
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

Now, I want know the API call to retrieve pharmacy information.

Comment: Are you referring to the map API? Please make your question more detailed, so we can see what you want, and what you have tried.

Comment: Yes. I am looking for Map API.   Below URL displays the Hospitals information. Same way I want to retrive  the pharmacy information. https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=51.498828,-0.117844&radius=500&types=hospital&key=AIzaSyA9xkXymeluJ8utaITKDw4GtOAy7nem28U

Comment: What happens if you try `types=pharmacy`? Is there a list of map feature types that Google does support?

Comment: I used the pharmacy. Its working. I have one more Question. That is Google maps displaying the data for below  longitude and latitude https://www.google.com/maps/search/hospital/@41.6637935,-70.9279159,12z/data=!3m1!4b1?hl=en                                                                    But its not working for my below query https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=41.6637935,-70.9279159&radius=500&types=hospital&key=AIzaSyA9xkXymeluJ8utaITKDw4GtOAy7nem28U   Can you help me  on this?

Comment: (I suggest you reset your private Google Maps key via your admin panel, now that you have published it in comments here. It is worth taking care to keep this secret at all times).

Answer (score 3):

[See this information](https://developers.google.com/places/supported_types) on specifying types in a place search.  "pharmacy" is a valid place type.

A simple change of the "types=" parameter in your query string like so will provide you pharmacies.

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=51.498828,-0.117844&radius=500&types=pharmacy&key=xxxxxx

```
{
   "html_attributions" : [],
   "results" : [
      {
         "geometry" : {
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 51.501325,
               "lng" : -0.111844
            }
         },
         "icon" : "http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/electronics-71.png",
         "id" : "78161653b1ae2efa586106f0324a9c559f64f313",
         "name" : "Boots",
         "opening_hours" : {
            "open_now" : true,
            "weekday_text" : []
         },
         "place_id" : "ChIJRw8qfLkEdkgR93mgxbvKFPE",
         "reference" : "CmRZAAAAMdS_-2MmZbUXXAd-ncstJuo3nIElyZuQX7huaZXD1zxS_PuLrBlyVFt9ih3MCuicALgXhrpDyVG1zRiS_EaW_UqMthNFAVbclJorO1a2KG2brmVfqKX0NI5H7wTYn30cEhCj98HsqGs3keyY5SCmQXyBGhQODo2FyrqT6cM8koHarj1tN670_Q",
         "scope" : "GOOGLE",
         "types" : [ "pharmacy", "electronics_store", "store", "health", "establishment" ],
         "vicinity" : "98-99 Lower Marsh"
      },
      {
         "geometry" : {
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 51.496145,
               "lng" : -0.111999
            }
         },
         "icon" : "http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/generic_business-71.png",
         "id" : "9b96fec6d819e6bb022373c3c4ead3daffda59b1",
         "name" : "Lloyds Pharmacy",
         "opening_hours" : {
            "open_now" : true,
            "weekday_text" : []
         },
         "place_id" : "ChIJ_VzIe74EdkgRXPqy77C3jMs",
         "reference" : "CnRjAAAAq1hFZVlk7UyyGjQGB_E0Epf4uZDMX6DuhuT_0-6VnnKU4n7lr5DLFSuYPfw5Nx5YXRjcxOQnRweA2PuN0B2E20dAXiqY2k0Hu6O8nq3WFpUBsFfUM4nl0hBmuTWgau1IfsxsSEFTGVOTDC2oegN9hRIQuGOqahaBuQbPIjUmpoPrNxoULU5yuHIqdDo3TgiHYhMheL5vomc",
         "scope" : "GOOGLE",
         "types" : [ "pharmacy", "store", "health", "establishment" ],
         "vicinity" : "76 Kennington Road, Lambeth"
      },
      {
         "geometry" : {
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 51.503024,
               "lng" : -0.112728
            }
         },
         "icon" : "http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/generic_business-71.png",
         "id" : "85679a68924b3310604b20750d04b7b8b1c10c55",
         "name" : "Boots",
         "opening_hours" : {
            "open_now" : true,
            "weekday_text" : []
         },
         "place_id" : "ChIJbd6czrkEdkgRC-cR14v3YR0",
         "reference" : "CmRYAAAAvauSHJ_omfGIXe4N3n8J4FO7SGMhvQESgk_nEJWpIchOnsIXuQt1AdEIGd2Y5sV5z1jpV--XhNNdrbH74_rvDdYm7vX-2l3F0wukFrIm8OC7zMNgKSq-a5SwMHffU6VfEhDYC9zVokwFD_vJdAGp0a8_GhS_AGHtX_gz4A0a0bgh7e4RRDDSYQ",
         "scope" : "GOOGLE",
         "types" : [ "pharmacy", "store", "health", "establishment" ],
         "vicinity" : "Waterloo Station, Waterloo Road, London"
      },
      {
         "geometry" : {
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 51.497177,
               "lng" : -0.11203
            }
         },
         "icon" : "http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/generic_business-71.png",
         "id" : "c7a5daf57e1edca6fb886c345b78fe0b5d8f3d6a",
         "name" : "CAM Pharmacy",
         "opening_hours" : {
            "open_now" : true,
            "weekday_text" : []
         },
         "photos" : [
            {
               "height" : 222,
               "html_attributions" : [],
               "photo_reference" : "CnRnAAAAc3xji4m70IeEWBI1pjUHl5a-OsqcAGoQmOUnQEc7zp2xU6Sgowp1dC_McR_TBhvdZGRoHMOGdxliZDxInhtDaTkJ6CcYdajX1DxgfgYA-9DTy4Pe6XwYnEefrAUvAscizeYi2x787lv78kq4cFmMKxIQAtu6clI2OReJYAvhsbfeQRoU93nWfekOeH6cR5dX6ok1lf4B5So",
               "width" : 300
            }
         ],
         "place_id" : "ChIJDfHIhL4EdkgR4QDArTYnvUo",
         "reference" : "CmRfAAAAgiv0i2taYk0ZinZhczjKCOAgbE71A2QjYJEp_3rimEDp83xup74AIPgkI9yd9Ol2SxBChQ-eH5KODua_Hba0bITjAE8uO9MtmS-9MniN9vrhLGtFcfzdaAc6WebXEwLdEhCe3qI8i3L9THjfudqqXAs3GhQzfpH9X2fZzEak6pQnr6jBWeGHFg",
         "scope" : "GOOGLE",
         "types" : [ "pharmacy", "food", "store", "health", "establishment" ],
         "vicinity" : "44 Kennington Road, London"
      },
      {
         "geometry" : {
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 51.503045,
               "lng" : -0.112682
            }
         },
         "icon" : "http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/electronics-71.png",
         "id" : "d90ef294c096c9860c20d45292f1ca9ea134b0f4",
         "name" : "Boots",
         "place_id" : "ChIJRx2hIroEdkgRhKg1MlOihYI",
         "reference" : "CmRZAAAAfRE4_DHxcfHUTcNuKTUjfxFMN9g5jWBingtYLGokT08f_HLVNR7w4iC6qE_NghIp0a_0weUMVLLig6lvbfRXJsVK87xuNuj5x-D1LWHObh7e1FPunB6Mxh_MAJXjQKDWEhAqYCC8amaUq2Gnl4CihfLfGhTFpjeXlmwUNCvOcgje_FMMKEDc3A",
         "scope" : "GOOGLE",
         "types" : [ "pharmacy", "electronics_store", "store", "health", "establishment" ],
         "vicinity" : "Waterloo Station, London"
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

**Note: I've removed your API key from the url in the question and this answer.  You might want to edit it in your comments as well**

Comment: I don't think this question is asking about Google's web search APIs. Also, the shutoff date was about six months ago; "will be" should be "has been". :)

Comment: @duskwuff: Good point on the date -- I updated the response.  The end user's english lacks clarity, but they specifically mention API several times in terms of "retrieve the information form Google."  If you don't think they are asking about the web search API, what is it that you think the question is about?

Comment: Given the [google-maps] tag, I suspect they're using a Maps or Places API.

Comment: @duskwuff: Noted and amended. :)

Comment: Yes. I am looking for Map API.   Below URL displays the Hospitals information. Same way I want to retrive  the pharmacy information. https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=51.498828,-0.117844&radius=500&types=hospital&key=AIzaSyA9xkXymeluJ8utaITKDw4GtOAy7nem28U

Comment: I used the pharmacy. Its working. I have one more Question. That is Google maps displaying the data for below  longitude and latitude https://www.google.com/maps/search/hospital/@41.6637935,-70.9279159,12z/data=!3m1!4b1?hl=en                                                                    But its not working for my below query https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=41.6637935,-70.9279159&radius=500&types=hospital&key=AIzaSyA9xkXymeluJ8utaITKDw4GtOAy7nem28U   Can you help me on this?

Comment: @Nagendra: that sounds like a new question. Would you post one, including all the necessary detail, and clarify (there not here) what "not working" actually means? (i.e. what did you expect, what actually happened, what errors you got, etc).

Comment: Not working - Not showing the expected result .                                             I am expecting the Hospitals information in New bedford city. Google maps displays the data when I was type Hospitals in New bedford in google maps.  In my query I am not getting the same result which displays in new bedford city.